# Can I add a fingerprint without allowing it to unlock the phone?

Tags: lineageos, 7.1-nougat

Some of my more secure applications offer fingerprint unlocking. This would be convenient to use, and I don't foresee any security issues with someone using my fingerprint because I would have had to have unlocked the phone with a pattern for someone to gain access to the application.

On the other hand, if the phone can be unlocked with my fingerprint as well, someone could unlock it while I am incapacitated (e.g. sleeping) without my knowledge, and then unlock the high-security applications as well. Having a pattern is a great form of two-factor authentication IMO.

I added a fingerprint to my rooted phone which runs LineageOS 14.1, Android version 7.1.1 -- this automatically allowed unlocking the phone via fingerprint. I cannot find a setting to disable this without removing the fingerprint and being unable to use it in any of my apps. Is there any way I can forcefully disable fingerprint authentication on the lock screen, but retain access to fingerprint unlocking for various apps without using a custom lock screen?

Here are the options I have for the lock screen and fingerprints -- I do not see any way to disable fingerprint authentication without removing the fingerprint, from the settings at least:

[image: A][image: A][image: A][image: A]

Answer (score 0):

The exact thing as you want is not possible on Android.

You can try using a third Party AppLocker App to secure your Applications while unlocking your phone with your Fingerprint, but I would not recommend any uncertified 3rd Party software protecting my apps.

Answer (score -2):

Check this link to disable fingerprint unlock on Samsung Galaxy S5 (maybe it works for you):
**[How to disable Fingerprint Unlock](http://support.bell.ca/Mobility/Smartphones_and_mobile_internet/Samsung-Galaxy-S5.how_to_disable_fingerprint_unlock_on_my_samsung)**

---

**Summary of the link:**

1. Go to *Settings->Lock Screen->
   Screen Lock*
   (*Settings->Security* in some devices)
2. Select any other method to unlock the screen instead of 'Fingerprint Unlock'

Comment: @cipher how does that answer OP's question?

Comment: To clarify, I want to disable fingerprint unlocking while still having the pattern lock screen. The first image in the OP shows that Pattern is already selected, and that there is no separate fingerprint option. I have now added two more images which give a better overview of my security settings. Clicking the "cog" on Screen Lock (3rd image) does not provide an option to disable fingerprint unlocking either. The 4th image shows all security settings.